# SQL select filter column based on another column

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I've got some data like:

| val | chr1 | chr2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | x1 |
| 2 | a | y2 |
| 3 | a | z3 |
| 4 | b | x1 |
| 5 | b | y2 |
| 6 | b | z3 |

I want to select data, so that in the result if chr1 = 'a' then chr2 only has x1, otherwise don't filter chr2 i.e :

| val | chr1 | chr2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | x1 |
| 4 | b | x1 |
| 5 | b | y2 |
| 6 | b | z3 |

I have the restriction due to a platform I'm forced to use, that I can only filter using the WHERE condition of the query, on Redshift.

Comment: `where (chr1 = 'a' and chr2 = 'x2') or chr1 <> 'a'` in case there's no nulls. Just translate general spoken words to conditions

Comment: I think you have a typo in your question, `x2` instead of `x1`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following logic:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE chr1 <> 'a' OR chr2 = 'x1';
```

So a whitelisted record is one which does not have `chr1 = 'a'`, *or* a record which does have this value but also has `chr2 = 'x1'`.

Comment: removed reference to x2 in the question apologies.

Comment: Won't this also exclude chr2 = x2 or y3 ?

Comment: Why don't you test my answer and then comment afterwards?

Comment: Yeah this excluded things I wanted in my results set

Comment: @user124123 My query is [working in this demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=96ea592a3f4c3d5a805dd8b91f895353).  You either left out some required logic, or else you didn't show us the right sample data.